# How to cope with ISO 8859-1 in gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an existing site using ISO 8859-1 I cannot change to UTF-8. When I use this script, accent characters are broken. How can I tell Gulp to take into account ISO 8859-1 :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

var inject = require('gulp-inject-string');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(inject.before('</body>', '<script src="myscript.js"></script>\n'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test'));
    console.log('myscript.js injected');
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding  wild guess

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks seems great will try

Comment: @RobertRowntree it detects but it does not save to ISO ?